# Webpack: Global var for use in non-module code

Tags: typescript, webpack, umd

I'm trying to make use of Typescript UMD modules (which don't fallback to a global var when require() doesn't exist) with legacy code that is not in any module pattern.

I was hoping that Webpack would have a loader or plugin that would create global vars for specific modules (instead of loading them as modules).

For example I have Typescript UMD module in a Node package:

```
node_modules/my-new-module
```

Which exports a function

```
myNewFunction(){ }
```

And I want to use it in my legacy code as:

```
myNewModule.myNewFunction(); //myNewModule is a global variable
```

Currently my best solution is to load all my shared modules in and manually assign them to globals. Of course this isn't ideal.

Can Webpack do this? Is there another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Webpack, you can expose your module as a library (global var will be generated):

> If library is set and libraryTarget is not, libraryTarget defaults to
>   var as specified in the output configuration documentation. See
>   output.libraryTarget there for a detailed list of all available
>   options.

Take a look here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#add-librarytarget

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. I had hoped that the application consuming the package/module could have chosen to load it as global vars. Using the library approach each package will need a 'library' and module version and the consuming application will choose which to implement. Still it solves the problem.